# Execute javascript code downloaded from a random website

Tags: javascript, security

I made a tool that grabs all html, css, javascript and images from other websites (any kind).
Then i execute this on my own domain name (after modification of links of course).

The javascript also executes, so the page render is identical as on the grabbed website. But all under my domain name.

Is there any method to secure this javascript execution (with uncontrolled code) so that the grabbed site will not be able to get cookies of the users of my website ? (or other potential security breach?)

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just use an iframe?

Comment: This whole thing is one big security breach. There is no way to secure this, it's impossible to sandbox JavaScript *from within JavaScript*.

Comment: By doing what you describe, you're implementing security breaches people usually try to avoid...

Comment: I execute code from website that my users have interest in. So i can take control of the page and add additionnal features for the user to select parts of the page...

Comment: And what do you do when one of your users add a website with malicious content?

Comment: May be alternatively, i should get the page rendered by phantomjs, then remove all javascript, and insert mine.

Yes NilsH that's the risk i am facing

Comment: _“I execute code from website that my users have interest in. So i can take control of the page and add additionnal features for the user to select parts of the page...”_ – write a bookmarklet or browser extension for that, so that the user can stay on the original domain.

Comment: I smell copyright infringement.

Comment: It's never nice to "steal" content and present it as your own anyway, if you ask me. If it is made by someone else, then credit it such by showing that it is in fact on their domain.

Comment: I am not law expert, But this looks to me like any anonymizer , or google cache. But that is a good point to think on the copyright stuffs

Answer (score 0):

Running the random page on a separate origin (i.e. running it on a separate domain) will at least avoid data leaks (cookies, localStorage, etc) between the random page and your site. To avoid leaks from one random page to an other, maybe also run each random page on its own sub-domain.

I believe this is what google does for the cache; the pages are served from the `googleusercontent.com` domain: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a

There is no way to prevent data leaks without running the page on a separate domain.

Answer (score 0):

thought you should never execute random js on your page.
still i think there is one way to do it though it requires huge amount of effort.

onces your pages gets loaded. override all the global variables of javascript that the browser injects to your own implementation and implement security checks in there. this way all the random js  being executed in your page will access all the functionalities that way you want them to do

ex. override document.cookie to something else on pageload which then execludes that cookies of your domain. 
change the protoype of xmlHttprequest so that ajax requests to your domain are blocked. etc etc